# Git log grep: How to match commit-message substrings regardless of word-order?

Tags: regex, git, grep, git-log, git-grep

I tried this

```
git log -i --all --grep='/(?=.*fix)(?=.*a)(?=.*bug)/'
```

but did not work.

Comment: Just `fix\|a\|bug`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues:

- When using `grep`, the regex pattern is not passed inside regex delimiters, but as  a regular string
- The PCRE-compliant pattern you used might not work as the default `git grep` regex engine is POSIX BRE flavor
- The pattern you used matches `fix`, `a` or `bug` in any order on the same line *but* requires them all to be present. To match specified strings in any order you need alternation patterns, e.g. `a|b|c`. However, in POSIX BRE, alternation operator is not supported, although the POSIX extension available in GNU tools allows the use of `\|` alternation operator version.

So, if you plan to match entries with these 3 words in any order, you need to remove regex delimiters and enable PCRE regex engine:

```sh
git log -i -P --all --grep='^(?=.*fix)(?=.*a)(?=.*bug)'
```

Note the `-P` option that enables the PCRE regex engine. Also, mind what documentation says:

```
-P
--perl-regexp
Consider the limiting patterns to be Perl-compatible regular expressions.

Support for these types of regular expressions is an optional compile-time dependency. If Git wasn’t compiled with support for them providing this option will cause it to die.
```

If you want to match entries with any of the words, you can use

```sh
git log -i -E --all --grep='fix|a|bug'
```

With `-E` option, POSIX ERE syntax is enforced, and `|` is an alternation pattern in this regex flavor.

To match them as whole words, use `\b` or `\<`/`\>` word boundaries:

```sh
git log -i -E --all --grep='\<(fix|a|bug)\>'
git log -i -E --all --grep='\b(fix|a|bug)\b'
```

**NOTE for Windows users**:

In Windows Git CMD or Windows console, `'` must be replaced with `"`:

```sh
git log -i -P --all --grep="^(?=.*fix)(?=.*a)(?=.*bug)"
git log -i -E --all --grep="\b(fix|a|bug)\b"
```

Comment: This git log -i -P --all --grep='^(?=.*fix)(?=.*a)(?=.*bug)' working fine for me on Ubuntu, however having some issues using PCRE on Mac. I am trying to solve those and will update here.

Answer (score 2):

> however having some issues using PCRE on Mac. I am trying to solve those and will update here

Make sure to use Git 2.40 (Q1 2023): newer regex library macOS stopped enabling GNU-like enhanced BRE, where '`\(A\|B\)`' works as alternation, unless explicitly asked with the `REG_ENHANCED` flag.

This is now fixed. (See [git mailing-list discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/f82ae28a-fb56-8d1f-96c8-550b61439d3a@enterprisedb.com/T/#u))
That way, `git-grep` would behave the same as `grep(1)` on each platform, which is consistent with the principle of least astonishment (POLA). On macOS, plain `git grep` should use enhanced basic REs.

"[`git grep`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5427bb4893e29a9502bbee5aed84c3b26e1a4e15/Documentation/git-grep.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep))</sup> now can be compiled to do so, to retain the old behaviour.

See [commit 54463d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54463d32ef6798c772c8bbf69b2c1897a854db9f) (08 Jan 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5427bb4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5427bb4893e29a9502bbee5aed84c3b26e1a4e15), 23 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`54463d32ef`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/54463d32ef6798c772c8bbf69b2c1897a854db9f):use enhanced basic regular expressions on macOS
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Marco Nenciarini</sup>
> <sup>Suggested-by: Jeff King</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> When [1819ad3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1819ad327b7a1f19540a819813b70a0e8a7f798f) ("`grep`: fix multibyte regex handling under macOS", 2022-08-26, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/410a0e520dcc91d13f77fd812f068161859883fc) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e85701b4af5b7c2a9f3a1b07858703318dce365d)) started to use the native regex library instead of Git's own (compat/regex/), it lost support for alternation in basic regular expressions.
>
> Bring it back by enabling the flag `REG_ENHANCED` on macOS when compiling basic regular expressions.

---

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), the userdiff regexp patterns for various filetypes that are built into the system have been updated to avoid triggering regexp errors from UTF-8 aware regex engines.

See [commit be39144](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be391449542d8a67cb343ec9d0b2f6854d665354) (06 Apr 2023) by [René Scharfe (`rscharfe`)](https://github.com/rscharfe).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit cbfe844](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cbfe844aa1b6b0b9513f2ae2fc3d18ff3dd385e6), 20 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`userdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be391449542d8a67cb343ec9d0b2f6854d665354): support regexec(3) with multi-byte support
>
> <sup>Reported-by: D. Ben Knoble</sup>
> <sup>Reported-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: René Scharfe</sup>

> Since [1819ad3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1819ad327b7a1f19540a819813b70a0e8a7f798f) ("`grep`: fix multibyte regex handling under macOS", 2022-08-26, Git v2.39.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/410a0e520dcc91d13f77fd812f068161859883fc) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e85701b4af5b7c2a9f3a1b07858703318dce365d)) we use the system library for all regular expression matching on macOS, not just for git grep.
> It supports multi-byte strings and rejects invalid multi-byte characters.
>
> This broke all built-in userdiff word regexes in UTF-8 locales because they all include such invalid bytes in expressions that are intended to match multi-byte characters without explicit support for that from the regex engine.
>
> "`|[^[:space:]]|[\xc0-\xff][\x80-\xbf]+`" is added to all built-in word regexes to match a single non-space or multi-byte character.
> The `\xNN` characters are invalid if interpreted as UTF-8 because they have their high bit set, which indicates they are part of a multi-byte character, but they are surrounded by single-byte characters.
>
> Replace that expression with "`|[^[:space:]]`" if the regex engine supports multi-byte matching, as there is no need to have an explicit range for multi-byte characters then.
> Check for that capability at runtime, because it depends on the locale and thus on environment variables.
> Construct the full replacement expression at build time and just switch it in if necessary to avoid string manipulation and allocations at runtime.
>
> Additionally the word regex for tex contains the expression "`[a-zA-Z0-9\x80-\xff]+`" with a similarly invalid range.
> The best replacement with only valid characters that I can come up with is "`([a-zA-Z0-9]|[^\x01-\x7f])+`".
> Unlike the original it matches NUL characters, though.
> Assuming that tex files usually don't contain NUL this should be acceptable.